# Game testing solutions?

Tags: unity, browser-based-games, testing

I have a unity web browser game. Since I'm working on a small company with limited machines which are all of either 2GB RAM or 4 GB RAM with decent processors. I'd like to know if there are any web based or software 'solutions' to test the game with low configuration both hardware and network bandwidth.

And, I have tried cross-browser testing solutions, But I didn't see any solution with the option of testing a browser game made for the unity web player .

Comment: Try asking at the Unity forums, for Unity community support. They are EXTREMELY helpful at the Unity community, and you would find tons of DEVELOPERS who fully understand what information you may need, and how they can help test it for you by doing what they know needs to be done.

Comment: For testing network bandwidth, see question "[How can I simulate a bad internet connection for testing purposes?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61483/how-can-i-simulate-a-bad-internet-connection-for-testing-purposes)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Unity community or just Open Alpha and get free testesr who will play the gamef or you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought of making your game Open Source and giving it out for people to test? If that would ruin things for you, have you thought of asking in popular gaming forums for testers? Posting a few screenshots can quickly attract a lot of players; most of which won't like your game. However, that is good. You can get a lot of information as to the flaws in your game from exit polling those users.

I vehemently encourage getting closed alpha testers for your game. Those who like it, will certainly help you test in future versions as well as secure a following.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for some game testing farm, they can do your work very easily... however before that you must look for free solutions... all the best..

Alax,
Game tester at [GameCloud](http://gamecloud-ltd.com)