# Testers for multiplayer game? Where to find them?

Tags: multiplayer, testing, playtesting

I am indie game developer and we created multiplayer and realtime game IQ Wars (www.iqwars.net). We made Windows/Mac/Linux Beta version of our game public and were hoping to find some beta testers to see if it works without problems with 50+ or 100+ players playing simultaneously.

So basically I was thinking about some kind of page or service were indie game developers publish their games so gamers can play and give (or not) some feedback. Is there any place where I can put the game (it's Setup.exe) or link to the game? Or maybe my understanding is wrong and I have to do it some other way?

Would be very appreciated for help.

Answer (score 2):

I could list some websites where you could announce your game, but the process to find non-paying players is pretty much the same as the one to find paying players. That means I would just be duplicating the answers to "[How can I promote my game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/how-can-i-promote-my-game)" and similar questions.

The problem with public beta tests is that they easily escalate to a PR event for the game, which can be a mistake if the product is not yet polished enough for the public. A professional studio would pay beta testers and have them sign an NDA which forbids them from talking about the game and all of its bugs and flaws, but I have the impression that this is outside of your budget constraints.

When it is just about stress testing your server technology, you might consider writing a headless bot to play your game and start a few hundred instances of that bot. The advantage of this is that you can easily scale the load accurately and also repeat your test with minimal organization overhead when you want to find out how some minor changes affect the overall performance. When you would like to simulate real-world network performance as well, you might want to take a look at the question "[How can I simulate a bad internet connection for testing purposes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61483/how-can-i-simulate-a-bad-internet-connection-for-testing-purposes)".

It can sometimes be hard to accurately simulate player behavior, because players sometimes behave in ways which are hard to predict for the developer which might result in far different server load than expected. That's why it is a good idea to have a small circle of testers you trust personally whose behavior you can use as a basis for your bots behavior.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I totally agree with your answer and yes I did bot testing to check if or to be more precise what load our server can handle. But the problem is that our game server by game logic should synchronize inputs  and broadcast synchronized messages to all connected players. So what I am trying to say is that it would be really interesting to see what happens in real world scenario with all network delays and etc which.But probably I have to rethink my bot testing scenario and include simulation of network collisions.

Comment: @Tony in that case, the question "[How can I simulate a bad internet connection for testing purposes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61483/how-can-i-simulate-a-bad-internet-connection-for-testing-purposes)" might be interesting to you.

Comment: 10 This was exactly what I wanted to ask. Thanks a lot. But my first task now is to do proper search in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com so I don't ask duplicate questions in future :(